# Find usages of a generic class with specific constraint

Tags: c#, visual-studio

As per title, how can I find usages of the method **Process** for `Processor<int>` rather than `Processor<string>`?

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main()
    {
        var processorInt = new Processor<int>();
        var processorString = new Processor<string>();

        processorInt.Process();
        processorString.Process();
    }
}

internal class Processor<T>
{
    public void Process() => Console.WriteLine(typeof(T).Name);
}
```

Comment: You're looking for a solution without ReSharper I suppose? (as it's pretty much straightforward with R#)

Comment: I'm using ReSharper, so also a good answer.

Answer (score 4):

ReSharper can handle this out of the box. If you try to perform a search for references, it'll actually ask you what you want to look for. Just declare a dummy variable of the type you want to look for, and call *Find Usages*, **on the type name**.

[image: Find Usages]

Note that this works for generic classes and generic methods, but it won't help you if you're looking for usages of a method in a generic class with a given type parameter.

[image: Generic method example]

Or just use *Right click* -> *Find usages advanced*:

[image: Find Usages Advanced]

Comment: That is a very nice feature!

Comment: This works for the class, not for the method. But it's a nice feature.

Comment: @Uno that's right, thanks for pointing it out. I added that to the answer.

Comment: Unfortunately I am looking for the usages of a non-generic method in a generic class...

Comment: @user4388177 hmm then I'm afraid you're out of luck with this method... A working implementation would have to search for generics transitively (eg if `SomeMethod<T>` calls `Processor<T>.Process`, you'd have to also find all invocations of `SomeMethod<int>`) - so I suppose that's the reason why R# searches for all `T`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't using standard tools.

You either have to:

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to find all references to `Processor<T>`.
2. Visually filter on `Processor<int>` yourself.

Or:

Find all using text search on `Processor<int>`. This is not very useful when you have `SomeOtherProcessor<int>` too, since that would match too.

This are the only options I have come up with. Other developer tools, like Resharper, might have an option that is better.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear in the question, this is a good answer, but I was looking for usages of the method Process().

Comment: More or less the same. There is no easy way to do this.

Comment: It's not really a solution as in the find tab you just see the name of the variable.

Comment: So, not easy to do. This is as close as you get.

Answer (score 0):

I fear the only way to achieve this is by directly searching for `Processor<int>()` within the search-and-replace-tool. Quite annoying though. However this won´t help ypu much if your generic class has a generic interface-parameter instead of a struct or class. Thus you cannot search for usages of `Processor<MyInterface>()`  when you are interested on occurences of all `Processor` with a generic parameter of that interface.

Answer (score 0):

You can use my tool built with Roslyn APIs:

https://github.com/UnoSD/SubTypeReferencesAnalysis